# jQuery Ajax XMLHttpRequest Progress Listener

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to add a progress bar to each upload of an asynchronous form for a Django website. My code is as follows. I'm not sure why, but at some point recently, I stopped being able to see the progress bar progress in this template. Am I missing something? I think this is a scope error of some sort but I'm not sure how to fix it. Please feel free to give me any hints you might have.
The code is as follows:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
       <form id="post-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Post
            <p style="text-align: right;">
                <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="{% url 'photobooth:photobooth' %}">Booth</a>
                {% if not request.GET.schedule %}<a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="?schedule=t{% if request.GET.camera %}&camera=t{% endif %}{% if request.GET.audio %}&audio=t{% endif %}"><i class="bi bi-calendar-fill"></i></a>{% endif %}
                {% if not request.GET.camera %}<a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="?camera=t{% if request.GET.schedule %}&schedule=t{% endif %}{% if request.GET.audio %}&audio=t{% endif %}"><i class="bi bi-camera-fill"></i></a>{% endif %}
                {% if not request.GET.audio %}<a class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="?audio=t{% if request.GET.camera %}&camera=t{% endif %}{% if request.GET.schedule %}&schedule=t{% endif %}"><i class="bi bi-mic-fill"></i></a>{% endif %}
            </p>
        </legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div id="uploaded_image"></div>
            <hr>
            <p id="contentLength"></p>
        <div id="progressBars"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
            </div>
        <p style="text-color: green;" class="hide" id="posted">Your post has been submitted.</p>
        </form>
{% endblock content %}
{% block javascript %}
var form = document.getElementById("post-form");
var posted = document.getElementById("posted");
var chooseFile = document.getElementById("id_image");
var imgPreview = document.getElementById("uploaded_image");
var counter = 0;
$(form).submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    form = document.getElementById("post-form");
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    form.reset();
    imgPreview.innerHTML = "";
    $("#progressBars").append('<progress id="progress' + counter + '" value="0" max="100" style="width: 100%">0%</progress>');
    var progress = document.getElementById("progress" + counter);
    counter++;
    $.ajax({
    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.counter = counter;
                xhr.counter = counter;
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                var progressBar = document.getElementById("progress" + evt.target.counter);
                progressBar.innerHTML = percentComplete + '%';
                progressBar.value = percentComplete;
            }
        });
        return xhr;
    },
        url: window.location.pathname,
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        timeout: 1000 * 60 * 30,
    success: function(data) {
        $(posted).toggleClass("hide");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(posted).toggleClass("fade-hidden");
            $(progress).toggleClass("fade-hidden");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(posted).toggleClass("hide");
                $(posted).toggleClass("fade-hidden");
                $(progress).toggleClass("hide");
                $(progress).toggleClass("fade-hidden");
            }, 2000);
        }, 2000);
    },
    });
});
chooseFile.addEventListener("change", function () {
  getImgData();
});
function getImgData() {
  const files = chooseFile.files[0];
  if (files) {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(files);
    fileReader.addEventListener("load", function () {
      imgPreview.style.display = "block";
      imgPreview.innerHTML = '<img width="100%" src="' + this.result + '" />';
    });    
  }
}
{% endblock %}
```

I also tried removing the latter progressBar = and changing it to progress, the variable, with no success. Could new browser updates have to do with this? What am I missing or doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a localization issue. using () => { } seems to work

```
`{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
       <form id="post-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Post
            <p style="text-align: right;">
                <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="{% url 'photobooth:photobooth' %}">Booth</a>
                {% if not request.GET.schedule %}<a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="?schedule=t{% if request.GET.camera %}&camera=t{% endif %}{% if request.GET.audio %}&audio=t{% endif %}"><i class="bi bi-calendar-fill"></i></a>{% endif %}
                {% if not request.GET.camera %}<a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="?camera=t{% if request.GET.schedule %}&schedule=t{% endif %}{% if request.GET.audio %}&audio=t{% endif %}"><i class="bi bi-camera-fill"></i></a>{% endif %}
                {% if not request.GET.audio %}<a class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="?audio=t{% if request.GET.camera %}&camera=t{% endif %}{% if request.GET.schedule %}&schedule=t{% endif %}"><i class="bi bi-mic-fill"></i></a>{% endif %}
            </p>
        </legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div id="uploaded_image"></div>
            <hr>
            <p id="contentLength"></p>
        <div id="progressBars"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
            </div>
        <p style="text-color: green;" class="hide" id="posted">Your post has been submitted.</p>
        </form>
{% endblock content %}
{% block javascript %}
var form = document.getElementById("post-form");
var posted = document.getElementById("posted");
var chooseFile = document.getElementById("id_image");
var imgPreview = document.getElementById("uploaded_image");
var counter = 0;
$(form).submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    form = document.getElementById("post-form");
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    form.reset();
    imgPreview.innerHTML = "";
    $("#progressBars").append('<progress id="progress' + counter + '" value="0" max="100" style="width: 100%">0%</progress>');
    var progress = document.getElementById("progress" + counter);
    $.ajax({
    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                var j = counter;
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", (evt) => {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                progress.innerHTML = percentComplete + '%';
                progress.value = percentComplete;
            }
                }, false);
        return xhr;
    },
        url: window.location.pathname,
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        timeout: 1000 * 60 * 30,
    success: function(data) {
        $(posted).toggleClass("hide");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(posted).toggleClass("fade-hidden");
            $(progress).toggleClass("fade-hidden");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(posted).toggleClass("hide");
                $(posted).toggleClass("fade-hidden");
                $(progress).toggleClass("hide");
                $(progress).toggleClass("fade-hidden");
            }, 2000);
        }, 2000);
    },
    });
    counter++;
});
chooseFile.addEventListener("change", function () {
  getImgData();
});
function getImgData() {
  const files = chooseFile.files[0];
  if (files) {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(files);
    fileReader.addEventListener("load", function () {
      imgPreview.style.display = "block";
      imgPreview.innerHTML = '<img width="100%" src="' + this.result + '" />';
    });    
  }
}`
```